# Projection onto subspace spanned by a single vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Given the vectors $x=(2,2,3)$ and $u_1=(0,3,0)$, vector $v_1$ is the projection of $x$ on the subspace spanned by $u_1$, so $v_1=\alpha u_1$.

Determine the value of $\alpha$.

**My attempt**

I haven't dealt with a case where the subspace is spanned by only one vector before. My textbook says that I can write the projection as a linear transformation:

$A^TA\alpha=A^Tx$

$A$ is the matrix that has the basis vectors as columns. The solution is $\alpha=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx$.

When I use this I get:

$A=\pmatrix{0\\3\\0}$

$A^TA=\pmatrix{0\\3\\0}(0,3,0)=9$

Then $(A^TA)^{-1}=\frac{1}{9}$, right?

So

$\alpha=\frac{1}{9}(0,3,0)(2,2,3)$

I can't multiply two row vectors. I must have done something wrong. Maybe I can't use the above formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for projection of a vector $v$ to another vector $u$ uses dot product:
$$\mathrm{proj}_u(v)= \frac{ v\cdot u}{u\cdot u}u$$
In the case you have given the projection is $\frac{0+6+0}{3}(0,9,0)= (0,2,0)=\frac{6}{9}u$.

Of course you can reformulate it using matrix product.

Comment: I get $u\cdot u=9$, so $proj_u(v)=(0,2,0)$.

Comment: That's correct.  Please make the correction.

Comment: I have submitted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The component of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{u_1}$ is:

$$
\mathbf{v_1}=\frac{\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{u_1}}{|\mathbf{u_1}|^2}\mathbf{u_1}
$$

Comment: Yes Thank you!  sorry for the typo.. I edit